# Finding injection on natural numbers?

Tags: functions

I would like to find an injection $f:\mathbb{N} \to  \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$

I thought of it as a chess board. Each field of $\mathbb{N}$ correspond to the board axes  $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{N}$. However I cant image the corresponding function doing that. Could someone provide some assistance?

Comment: Maybe he wanted an injection $\Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to \Bbb N$

Comment: Or perhaps a bijection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An injection in the desired direction is easy to obtain, for instance $n\mapsto (n,5)$ will work. It is more interesting to look for an injection $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$.

Comment: Or are you actually looking for a bijection?

Comment: No for an injection. I mean $2^a \times 3^b$ maps from $\Bbb N  \times\Bbb N \to\Bbb  N$ the other way around was not clear somehow

Comment: Okay, then my answer will work. Notice that people think it's easy to inject $\mathbb N$ into $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$ because the former is "smaller."

Comment: Nothing in particular. I just couldn think of a function. Im trying to get a better understanding of functions and struggle somehow...next project is to find the surjective for $\Bbb N  \times\Bbb N \to\Bbb  N$ :)

Answer (score 4):

Your are so near to an answer, that I don't want to say too much. Think about going diagonal over the chess board.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! As you may be aware of, this should be better suited as a comment rather than an answer, but you don't have enough reputation to do so. However, this is an answer so maybe you could elaborate a little bit more (without spoiling too much if you want, it is up to you), or shape your answer differently (Ex : "**Hint**: Try to..."). Upvoted because it is useful and so that you will be able to comment soon.

Comment: Offtopic: Thank you :). Yes, I know about the comment problem. Will be over it soon, I hope.

Answer (score 2):

The classic bijection $\Bbb N\times\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ is
$$(n,m)\longmapsto\frac{(n+m)(n+m+1)}2 + n.$$
Can you find the inverse?

Comment: That seems interesting...

Comment: This bijection is correct if $0 \in \mathbb{N}$. But it is easy to find a similar function in case $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: for example? I mean what is the general approach...just trying every function?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this is what I came up with: $N \triangleq \lfloor\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+8x}}{2}\rfloor$, then $n = x-\frac{N(N+1)}{2}$ and $m=N-n$.

Comment: @Ronald Actually, I think it doesn't work if $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$. Just try to think of the inverse of $1$. The definition should make an exception to that formula and include the case $n=m=0$ mapping to $0$.

Comment: @wood well, that's what I tried to say. The mapping in case $0 \notin \mathbb{N}$ should be something like $(n, m) \mapsto \frac{(n + m - 2)(n + m - 1)}{2} + n$